# The planar surface code vs the toric code

Tags: error-correction, surface-code, topological-quantum-computing

Where can I find a numerical or analytical comparison of the effect of open and closed boundaries on surface code error correction power, such as the logical error rate at the threshold, logical error rate scaling, etc?

In general, which code has a better error correction performance, the toric or the surface code?

It seems that in the toric code, there are fewer possible logical error chains per logical qubit, but there are two qubits while in the planar surface code, there is only one. So which of the effects will win in which regime (near the threshold, far from the threshold)?

Comment: It sounds like a simple question but it is difficult to find something in the literature!

I found this: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0531.pdf, where it seems that the toric code performs slightly better near the threshold, but the results are not conclusive and there is no explanation. On the other hand, in https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/handle/10044/1/31475 it seems that the two codes have the same performance. Here also there is no discussion of this result.

Comment: The two codes have different rates (k=1 vs k=2) so any comparison would have to be normalized somehow. Also performance is decoder dependent unless you have a theoretically optimal decoder for both.

Comment: Sure, but any possible normalization is ok for me - either logical error rate per logical qubit, logical error rate in any of the existing qubits, or logical error rate assuming a fixed number of logical qubits and a fixed overhead (such that in the surface code, we need two copies.

MWPM is usually used for benchmarking for the decoder, but any other is also ok with me.